# Azure App Service app does not update even though build completes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I'm not sure why my Azure Webapp (App service) isn't updating even though I see my updated code in the `main` branch in ADO. I've tried restarting the app as well and no change.

I noticed that on kudu `site/repository/` doesn't have the latest code.

[image]

This is my settings,

- `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1`
- `WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = true`
- `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = NEVER`
- `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0`

My YAML file is like so

```yaml
trigger:
- main

stages:
  - stage: SDL
    jobs:
    - <removed>

  - stage: BuildAndDeploy
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: 'Build and Publish'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps:
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
        inputs:
          version: '6.x'

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Archive project files'
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifactName: 'publishedApp'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'        

      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }}
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: ${{ variables.webAppName }}
          package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

edit: Current repo files

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes, please update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

From your screenshot of the Web App kudu, the web app is in the Read-Only Mode.

This is the reason why your web app content not update.

To solve this issue, you need to set the app setting: **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** to **0** or remove the **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE**.

[image]

Then you can re-run the Pipeline and the latest code will be deployed to the Azure Web App.

**Update:**

Based on your comment, you need to deploy the repository files to the `site\repository` path.

By default, AzureRmWebAppDeployment task will deploy the files to wwwroot folder

To meet your requirement, you can refer to the following steps:

Step: Create **Virtual applications** in **Azure Web App -> Configuration -> Path mappings -> Virtual applications and directories**.

You can set the **Physical path** to **site\repository**

For example:

[image]

**Note:** The type need to set to **Application**

Step2: You can add the `VirtualApplication: /virpath` to the AzureRmWebAppDeployment  task.

In this case, you need to change the **deploymentMethod** to **auto** in AzureRmWebAppDeployment task.

On the other hand, in Azure DevOps, the repo files will be checkout to $(Build.Sourcesdirectory). So you need to change the **rootFolderOrFile** to $(Build.Sourcesdirectory) in ArchiveFiles task.

Here is the  YAML example:

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
  - stage: SDL
    jobs:
    - <removed>

  - stage: BuildAndDeploy
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: 'Build and Publish'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps:
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
        inputs:
          version: '6.x'

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Archive project files'
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.Sourcesdirectory)'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifactName: 'publishedApp'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'        

      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }}
          appType: 'webApp'
          WebAppName: ${{ variables.webAppName }}
          VirtualApplication: /virpath
          package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that deleting or setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` just is reset to `1`, based on the documentation it should be `1` or a `url`, but not certain on the URL format.

Comment: Should my new\updated files end up in `site\repository`?

Comment: @Robert As far as I know, the files will be deployed to the wwwroot folder in kudu by default. You can check if you can see the new files in the wwwroot folder

Comment: And you can change to use the zipdeploy deployment method in AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4 task if you still not able to see the changes

Comment: There are files in the `wwwroot` folder, but from what I can tell not related to my project. I've also updated the yaml for `AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4` above but no change. I'm also at MSFT rob evans

Comment: @Robert From your yaml sample, it seems that you are using the path $(Build.BinariesDirectory) in Archive files task. This path could contain no files, can you check if the build artifacts has the required files in Azure Devops pipeline?

Comment: And can you share the expected file list sample in artifacts or kudu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257000/discussion-between-robert-and-kevin-lu-msft).

Comment: @Robert Based on your update, you need to deploy the files to `site\repository`. You can  refer to the update in the answer and do related changes. Then the files will be deployed to site\repository